# Cache problems in Drupal7

Tags: caching, drupal-7

I have a custom block that has cache disabled. However, when I make any change in content, that action has not result. The content doesn't show changes until I refresh the cache.

Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
if ($op == 'list') {
    $blocks[0]['info'] = t('My custom block');
    $blocks[0]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
    return $blocks;
  }
```